# Find the following limit and prove its value by definition. $\lim _{n\to \infty} (n^2 + 3n + 7)/(2n^2 −5n − 4)$.

Tags: complex-analysis

Find the following limit and prove its value by definition. $\lim_{n\to \infty} \frac{n^2 + 3n + 7}{2n^2 −5n − 4}$. I am supposed to use$$ \left|\frac{n^2 + 3n + 7}{2n^2 −5n − 4} - \frac{1}{2}\right| < ε $$then combine the fraction of the limit and the result and eventually get rid of the absolute value bars with some algebra and end up with one $n <$ some $ε$ but since neither the top nor bottom of the limit factor I do not know how I can manipulate the limit so my final inequality can be a single $n$ and some $ε$.

Comment: I recommend studying thewatcher's answer, which I upvoted.  I think that the approach is *generic* and so can be applied to all problems of this type.  If you are able to follow the answer, and agree with it, then I ask that you **accept** his answer, by clicking on the checkmark to the left of the answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since
$$\frac{n^2 + 3n +7}{2n^2-5n+4} - \frac{1}{2} = \frac{2n^2 + 6n +14 - 2n^2+5n-4}{4n^2-10n-8}  = \frac{11n-10}{4n^2-10n-8} $$

Then you could simply bound the right hand side,

$$|\frac{11n-10}{4n^2-10n-8} | \leq |\frac{11n}{4n^2-10n-8}| \leq |\frac{11n}{4n^2-11n}| = |\frac{11}{4n-11}| \leq |\frac{11}{4n-n}|  \leq \frac{11}{3n}$$
Where we used that $n$ has to bigger than $8$ and $11$, thus the above inequality holds for $n \geq 11$. We want, given $\varepsilon >0$, find an $n \in \mathbb N$ such
$$|\frac{11n-10}{4n^2-10n-8} |<\varepsilon,$$
but we can bound the upper term, in the following way:
$$|\frac{11n-10}{4n^2-10n-8} |< \frac{11}{3n}<\varepsilon$$
for $n \geq 11$. So we only have to find the $n$ that makes
$$\frac{11}{3n}<\varepsilon$$
true. But the previous inequality is equivalent to
$$ \frac{11}{3 \varepsilon} < n. $$ This means the inequality is true of $n$'s bigger than $\frac{11}{3 \varepsilon}$. We can take, for example, $n = \lceil \frac{11}{3 \varepsilon} \rceil + 1$. But don't forget a condition is also that $n \geq 11$! So finally,
$$n_0 = \max\left\{11, \left \lceil \frac{11}{3 \varepsilon} \right \rceil + 1 \right\} $$ is an $n$ that makes $|\frac{11n-10}{4n^2-10n-8} |<\varepsilon$ true.

Comment: I upvoted; nice.

Comment: +1 also for me. But why $|4n^2-10n-8|$ is upper bond by $|4n^2-11n|$?

Comment: @Sebastiano $|4n^2 - 11n| \leq |4n^2-10n-8|$ holds for $n \geq 8$, so $\frac{1}{|4n^2-10n-8|} \leq \frac{1}{|4n^2 - 11n|}$

Comment: It is true. I have read now better your answer :-( I'm sorry. "n  has to bigger than 8 and 11"

Answer (score 1):

After the first simplification we only need a bound as for example

$$ \frac{11n-10}{4n^2-10n-8} \le \frac{12n}{3n^2}=\frac 4 n$$

which holds as $n>10$, therefore assuming wlog $\varepsilon\le \frac 4 {10}$

$$ \left|\frac{11n-10}{4n^2-10n-8}\right| \le \frac 4 n<\varepsilon$$

which holds for any $n>\frac 4 \varepsilon$.

Answer (score 0):

If you continue with the long division, you will notice that
$$\frac{11n-10}{4n^2-10n-8}=\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac {a_k}{2 ^{k+1}\,n^k}$$ where the $a_k$ are all positive. The first ones make the sequence
$$\{11,35,263,1595,10079,\cdots\}$$ So, you can make it as tight as you wish.

For example, using the given terms and $n=10$, we should get $\frac{2187179}{6400000}\approx 0.3417$ while the exact value is $\frac{25}{73}\approx 0.3425$.